# Is there Any Study on the Sum of $e^{-\sqrt{n}t}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I've been messing around with some things after looking at Jacobi Theta Functions and I happened to stumble upon these unexpectedly (at least to me) nice Laurent expansion and integral representation of a curious sum:

$$
\begin{split}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty e^{-\sqrt{n}t}
&=
\frac12+\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\int_0^\infty\coth\left(\frac{t^2}{8x^2}\right)e^{-x^2}dx
\\
&=
\frac2{t^2}+\frac12-\frac1{\sqrt{\pi}}\sum_{n=1}^\infty \sin\left(\frac{\pi k}4\right) \frac{(-t)^k\zeta(1+\frac k2)}{(8\pi)^{k/2}\Gamma(\frac{1+k}{2})}
\end{split}
$$

Has this series been studied somewhere? Is there literature that I could possibly read on it? I don't even know what to call the thing, much less how to search for resources on it online.

Comment: Approach0 yields [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1864289/analytic-continuation-of-sum-sum-n-0-infty-e-b-sqrt-n?noredirect=1), [this one looking for other forms](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1035703/an-equivalent-for-sum-n-0-infty-e-x-sqrtn-as-x-tends-to-0?noredirect=1), and [one on its convergence](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1921840/radius-of-convergence-of-sum-n-0-infty-e-z2-sqrtn?noredirect=1)

Comment: I see, thank you very much!

Comment: This [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2287417/find-the-limiting-value-of-s-a-sqrt1a-sqrt2a-sqrt3a-sqrt4) is also relevant.